# Spark: Comparing two datasets

Tags: java, apache-spark

There is a spark job I am working on which reads data from parquet files from two different location. These parquet files are generated from two different sources but the same source.
I want to compare `Dataset<Row>` from these two parquet files and see if any column value got dropped.

Is there a way to compare two Datasets and show columns which do not match?

`Dataset<Row> parquetFile = spark
            .read()
            .parquet(""file"//file1.parquet);`

Comment: Project [Hermes](https://github.com/AbsaOSS/hermes) has a dataset-comparison module that might help you. Can be used as a library.

Answer (score 3):

The solution I have is in Scala but you can work it out in Java as well, since the idea is same.

There are multiple ways that I can think of when comparing two datasets/dataframes in spark, you can do df.except (twice, i.e. A - B and B - A), then join the two resultant dataframes but that's a whole lot of shuffles and is storage intensive if number of columns increases

This below method is the simplest, involves just one shuffle, works like a charm even with thousands of columns and millions of records :

```
  case class Person(name: String, age: Long)
  import spark.implicits._

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val source = Seq(Person("Andy", 32), Person("Farhan", 26), Person("John", 23)).toDS().toDF
    val target = Seq(Person("Andy", 32), Person("Farhan", 25), Person("John", 23)).toDS().toDF

    compareTwoDatasets(spark, source, target, "name").show(10, false)

  }

  def compareTwoDatasets(spark: SparkSession, sourceDS: Dataset[Row], targetDS: Dataset[Row], uniqueColumnName: String) = {

    val source = sourceDS.map(sourceRow => (sourceRow.getAs(uniqueColumnName).toString, sourceRow.mkString("|"))).toDF(uniqueColumnName, "source_record")
    val target = targetDS.map(targetRow => (targetRow.getAs(uniqueColumnName).toString, targetRow.mkString("|"))).toDF(uniqueColumnName, "target_record")
    val columns = sourceDS.columns
    source
      .join(target, uniqueColumnName)
      .where($"source_record" =!= $"target_record")
      .flatMap { row =>
        val sourceArray = row.getAs[String]("source_record").split("\\|", -1)
        val targetArray = row.getAs[String]("target_record").split("\\|", -1)
        val commonValue = row.getAs[String](uniqueColumnName)
        List(columns, sourceArray, targetArray)
          .transpose
          .filter(x => x(1) != x(2))
          .map((commonValue, _))

      }.toDF(uniqueColumnName, "mismatch_column_source_target")

  }
```

Output:

```
+------+-----------------------------+
|name  |mismatch_column_source_target|
+------+-----------------------------+
|Farhan|[age, 26, 25]                |
+------+-----------------------------+
```

where the value in second column will be, the mismatch column name, source value and its corresponding target value.

Answer (score 1):

Better answer in my view, but using DF and SCALA and more generic, so will work as well.

As an example, simulated input:

```
case class Person(personid: Int, personname: String, cityid: Int)
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df1 = Seq(
     Person(0, "AgataZ", 0),
     Person(1, "Iweta", 0),
     Person(2, "Patryk", 2),
     Person(9999, "Maria", 2),
     Person(5, "John", 2),
     Person(6, "Patsy", 2),
     Person(7, "Gloria", 222), 
     Person(3333, "Maksym", 0)).toDF

val df2 = Seq(
     Person(0, "Agata", 0),
     Person(1, "Iweta", 0),
     Person(2, "Patryk", 2),
     Person(5, "John", 2),
     Person(6, "Patsy", 333),
     Person(7, "Gloria", 2), 
     Person(4444, "Hans", 3)).toDF

val joined = df1.join(df2, df1("personid") === df2("personid"), "outer") 
val newNames = Seq("personId1", "personName1", "personCity1", "personId2", "personName2", "personCity2")
val df_Renamed = joined.toDF(newNames: _*)

// Some deliberate variation shown in approach for learning 
val df_temp = df_Renamed.filter($"personCity1" =!= $"personCity2" || $"personName1" =!= $"personName2" || $"personName1".isNull || $"personName2".isNull || $"personCity1".isNull || $"personCity2".isNull).select($"personId1", $"personName1".alias("Name"), $"personCity1", $"personId2", $"personName2".alias("Name2"), $"personCity2").  withColumn("PersonID", when($"personId1".isNotNull, $"personId1").otherwise($"personId2"))

val df_final = df_temp.withColumn("nameChange ?", when($"Name".isNull or $"Name2".isNull or $"Name" =!= $"Name2", "Yes").otherwise("No")).withColumn("cityChange ?", when($"personCity1".isNull or $"personCity2".isNull or $"personCity1" =!= $"personCity2", "Yes").otherwise("No")).drop("PersonId1").drop("PersonId2")

df_final.show()

gives:

+------+-----------+------+-----------+--------+------------+------------+   
|  Name|personCity1| Name2|personCity2|PersonID|nameChange ?|cityChange ?|
+------+-----------+------+-----------+--------+------------+------------+
| Patsy|          2| Patsy|        333|       6|          No|         Yes|
|Maksym|          0|  null|       null|    3333|         Yes|         Yes|
|  null|       null|  Hans|          3|    4444|         Yes|         Yes|
|Gloria|        222|Gloria|          2|       7|          No|         Yes|
| Maria|          2|  null|       null|    9999|         Yes|         Yes|
|AgataZ|          0| Agata|          0|       0|         Yes|          No|
+------+-----------+------+-----------+--------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: this isn't very generic, I'd rather use https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base

Answer (score 0):

At the very high level you can try the following:

1. Load your data from two locations into separate data frames `df1` and `df2`.
2. Join `df1` and `df2` on `id` field into `df3`
3. Write map function for `df3` where you compare left and right side of the join.
4. The return result from the map function could be something like a tuple containing the row id and the list of column name/value pairs that do not match.
5. Store the result or preview in the UI.